# Why clearinterval() does not stops the setInterval() in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to start the `setInterval` When the particular id is `2` and to clear the Interval using `clearInterval`.

When I click on the button, the value in the button should be `0,1,2,3,0,1,2...`.  When the value is 2, it should display `Date.now()`.

```
<button id="b1">0</button>
<button id="b2">0</button>
<button id="b3">0</button>
```

```
$("button").click(function () {
  buttonVal(this);
});

var v = [];

function buttonVal(ele) {
  v[ele.id] =
    typeof v[ele.id] === "undefined" ? 0 : v[ele.id] === 3 ? 0 : v[ele.id] + 1;
  switch (v[ele.id]) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case 1:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = v[ele.id];
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = v[ele.id];
      break;

    case 3:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = v[ele.id];
      break;

    default:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = 6;
      break;
  }
 if(v[ele.id] == 2) {
   
   var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
     v[ele.id] = {'refreshId': refreshId};
     document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = Date.now();
    }, 2000);
   }
  else {
    clearInterval(refreshId);
  }
}
```

The problem is `clearInterval()` is not working, When the button value is 2, it starts the `setInterval()`but it doesn't stops when the value is not 2. It just continues to run for all the button Values.

The button value runs like the below after clicking them `0,1,2,3, object1, object11, object111`. Not sure, why the order is like the above.

Could anyone please help to stop the timer for the values other than 2.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's probably because your `refreshId` is a local variable. You can make it global by declaring `var refreshId` outside of your functions. Then put `refreshId = setInterval()` in your function.

Comment: @Kokodoko completely right, when you call `clearInterval(refreshId)`, `refreshId` is `undefined` because variable was declared in other scope and cannot be accessed here.

Comment: @Xeelley To be clear, the variable is in scope. It’s *undefined* because it’s a new reference, hoisted and uninitialized when the condition is false.

Comment: @DaveNewton agree, you right, thanks for clarify!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `var refreshId` inside the if block, and trying to clear it in else, so the scope isn't the same. Your `refreshId` is a local variable.

Try defining it first outside the if block, or rather outside of the function itself.

```
var refreshId = null;

if(v[ele.id] == 2) {
 refreshId = setInterval(...)
 ...
else {
 clearInterval(refreshId);
}
```

Comment: It'll need to be declared outside the function, otherwise its value will have reset next time the function is called (which is when the clearing would happen, if you look at the logic)

Comment: `var` variables only scope in functions and globally. This would only be the problem with `const` and `let`

Comment: It’s local to the function, not the block. It will be re-created (and over-written) every time the conditional is true, and because of hoisting, will be `undefined` when the condition  is false.

Comment: @marko, added refreshId outside the if block, but still it didn't work. here is my codepen https://codepen.io/Davi9/pen/KKvyBME

Comment: @shada It’s still in the function; please consider reading the rest of this answer, the other answer, and all the comments.

Comment: @Dave,  I declared the var outside the function as suggested. But, still it didn't work.https://codepen.io/Davi9/pen/KKvyBME

Answer (score 1):

When running a function all variables get redeclared again, this means when you say: `var intervalId = interval(...)`. You create a new variable instead of saving it for later.

To solve this problem save the interval globally like shown below:

```js
let interval;

function buttonVal(ele) {
 // code...
 
 if(v[ele.id] == 2) {
   interval = setInterval(function(){
     v[ele.id] = {'refreshId': refreshId};
     document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = Date.now();
    }, 2000);
   }
  else {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(refreshId);
    }
  }
}
```